# Quotient group as colimit

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, limits-colimits

I have been wondering for a while about the following question without getting anywhere:

Let $G$ be a group, $N$ a normal subgroup. Can the quotient group $G/N$ be seen as the (category theoretical) colimit of a diagram? If it can, of what diagram?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the diagram $N \rightrightarrows G$ where one of the arrows is the inclusion and the other arrow is the zero map. (If $N$ is not necessarily normal you will instead get the quotient by the normal closure of $N$.) More generally, see [coequalizer](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coequalizer) and [cokernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cokernel).

Comment: If you want a detailed discussion of this and other related issues, Aluffi's "Algebra - chapter 0" does a great job.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you construct the *congruence* $\Theta = \{ (g,h) \in G^2 \mid g \equiv h \bmod N \} $ corresponding to $N$, and then $G/\Theta$ is the coequalizer of the two projection maps $\Theta \to G$.

By the respective definitions of a quotient by a congruence or a normal subgroup, $G /\Theta = G/N$, so that gives the colimit you desire.

**Grp** has a zero object, and thus *cokernels*; $G/N$ is the cokernel of the inclusion $i : N \to G$. Two ways to construct cokernels are:

- As the coequalizer of the two arrows $i : N \to G$ and $0 : N \to G$
- As the pushout of
  $$\require{AMScd}
  \begin{CD}
  N @>>> 0
  \\ @VVV @VVV
  \\ G @>>> G/N
  \end{CD} $$